# Creating a database with parent child hierarchy in MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, hierarchy

I was taking a look at this page of the mongo documentation, as I couldn't find any specific pymongo documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/

I am able to insert a document into my database with the following command:

```
>>> db.categories.insert( { "_id": "MongoDB", "parent": "Databases" } )
'MongoDB'
```

But when I reach this portion to use .parent, it isn't reognized and returns an error.

```
>>> db.categories.find_one( { "_id": "MongoDB" } ).parent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Is there some portion of the documentation I am following incorrectly, or some method to have parent child hierarchy that I don't know about? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.categories.find_one` is returning a dict, so you need to use correct get sematics: ie:

```
db.categories.find_one( { "_id": "MongoDB" } )["parent"]
```

probably best to add error checking too:

```
record = db.categories.find_one( { "_id": "MongoDB" } )
if record:
   parent = record["parent"]
```

In the article 'parent' refers to the parent key in the data that was added - not to a parent node in a hierarchal structure.

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense and thanks for the quick reply. So you're saying that the article and your demonstration only involve parent keys in data, and it's not possible to have a hierarchical parent child node structure?

Comment: The page gives you a number of strategies for how you would structure parent/nodes. You have to query the object, get its parent value, then you can perform a db.find() to find all other nodes with the same parent. Each entity is distinct when you insert into the db - there is no "built in" mechanism to work within a hierarchal structure: ie - you have to facilitate that yourself by adding, for example ,"parent" attributes in your data. hope that makes sense.